# How to use Greater Shadow Conjuration in Neverwinter Nights?

Tags: neverwinter-nights

Ok I am having Greater Shadow Conjuration Spell in  Neverwinter Nights 1 but I do not know how to use it (I can only summon some kind of "cat creature") ,but don't know how to use other spells like: acid arrow, ghostly visgae and minor globe...

Any help?

Comment: Thx that did the trick...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to click through the spell in the radial menu; It should open a sub-menu with the various permutations of the spell.